# Google Chrome not loading sp.ribbon.js file and other custom js files. Page not scrolling

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are testing out our SharePoint sites in Google Chrome and the page is not loading properly, mainly, none of the onload scripts in JQuery are executing and the Scroll Bar is not appearing.

On checking Developer Tools-> Network tab, we see that the related js files are not being retrieved over the internet at all, including the sp.ribbon.js

Although, the page does load completely sometimes.

Anybody any clue? Is it some setting in Chrome that we have to tweak?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the rendering of the search box control in `Google Chrome`.

Try adding `Visible="false"` to the `SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox" Version="4"` control on the master page.

That corrects the rendering issue for me.